# Create a CSV file by entering user-id and password, read and search the password for given userid

Tags: python

Create a CSV file by entering user-id and password, read and search the password for given user id.

can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open("7.csv", "w") as obj:
    fileobj = csv.writer(obj)
    fileobj.writerow(["User Id", "password"])
    while(True):
        user_id = input("enter id: ")
        password = input("enter password: ")
        record = [user_id, password]
        fileobj.writerow(record)
        x = input("press Y/y to continue and N/n to terminate the program\n")
        if x in "Nn":
            break
        elif x in "Yy":
            continue
with open("7.csv", "r") as obj2:
    fileobj2 = csv.reader(obj2)
    given = input("enter the user id to be searched\n")

    for i in fileobj2:
        next(fileobj2)

        # print(i,given)
        if i[0] == given:
            print(i[1])
            break
```